# Who was the train conductor who threw Gandhi from a first class train coach in South Africa?

Tags: south-africa

A pivotal moment in history, which catalyzed Gandhi's subsequent actions was his ejection from a first-class train carriage in South Africa by the train conductor, a story which is recounted in his autobiography: "[My Experiments with Truth](https://archive.org/details/AnAutobiographyOrTheStoryOfMyExperimentsWithTruth)".

Was it ever identified who this South African train conductor was, who unintentionally laid the seeds of many a freedom struggle. Thanks.

Comment: It is true that we know the [identity of Rosa Park's bus driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_F._Blake), so it appears such things are of interest.

Comment: @T.E.D. Commenting on his death, Rosa Parks said, "[I'm] sure his family will miss him."

Comment: @AllInOne - That line really jumped out at me too. At the end of an entry trying to say how he was really a nice guy after all, just doing his job in bad system, loved his family, etc. LOL. Gotta be one of my favorite interview answers ever.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, no. There are no recorded eyewitness accounts or other direct historical evidence of the incidents that I can find other than Gandhi's memoirs.

According to the article, "[Transforming our townscapes: the Pietermaritzburg experience](http://www.natalia.org.za/Files/45/Natalia%20No%2045%20Article%20Transforming%20townscapes.pdf)" by Robert F. Haswell, a historical marker was placed at the likely spot of the incident, but the location is based on inference. [An older article](http://natalia.org.za/Files/13/Natalia%20v13%20notes-%20queries%20C.pdf) published in the same journal discusses certain historical details of the incident that were inaccurately portrayed in [the relevant scene](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083987/characters/nm0923366) from the 1982 biopic, *Ghandi* and includes a relevant observation, again based on inference:

> the official who ejected Gandhi would probably have been Scots, not Dutch or Afrikaans

That seems to be about all we know, and unless a surprising new source of information emerges, all we will ever know.